# Quiescence search in a chess computer

Tags: search, artificial-intelligence, chess, heuristics

I'm developing a chess computer but have run into a problem with my quiescence search.

Take this chess position as an example:

[image: FEN: k7/2q5/2P5/3ppr2/4P3/8/8/K7]

If we search to depth one the best move would be `exf5`.

However, the computer also searches `exd5` and then go to the quiescence search. It there tries `Qxc6` and then `dxc6`, which gives a better position than `exf5` as the first move. The second player would of course not play `Qxc6` but I don't know how to make the quiescence search only look at *"good captures"*.

Does anyone here know how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Two well known methods are **MVV-LVA** (*Most Valuable Victim - Least Valuable Aggressor*) and **SEE** (*Static Exchange Evaluation*).

---

**MVV-LVA** is a simple heuristic to generate / sort capture moves in a reasonable order. Initially (MVV) the algorithm looks up the potential victim of all attacked opponent pieces, in the order of the most valuable first.

After the most valuable victim is found, the LVA identifies, in inverse order (Pawn, Knight, Bishop, Rook, Queen to King), the potential aggressors that may capture the victim.

It can fail but is easy to implement and covers a lot of simple cases.

---

**SEE** examines the consequence of a series of exchanges on a single square after a given move and calculates the likely evaluation change (material) to be lost or gained.

A good implementation is quite tricky.

---

For further details take a look at:

- [MVV/LVA. Or should it be LVV/MVA?](https://web.archive.org/web/20180820084552/http://www.talkchess.com/forum3/viewtopic.php?t=27254)
- [Static Exchange Evaluation on ChessProgramming](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Static_Exchange_Evaluation)
- [Explain SEE (static exchange evaluator)?](http://www.stmintz.com/ccc/index.php?id=134986)
- [MVV/LVA or SEE - liability?](http://www.stmintz.com/ccc/index.php?id=141813)